# Infinitely many Primes in Arithmetic progression $10n+9$

Tags: prime-numbers, algebraic-number-theory, analytic-number-theory, prime-gaps, coprime

Can anyone provide How J. A. Serret proved infinitude of primes in the arithmetic progression $10n+9$? 
I know there are many general proofs available now. But I want this one. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The book "Dickson - History of the Theory of Numbers, Volume I" cites that as appearing in the french journal "Jour. de Math, 17, 1852, 186-9". I wasn't able to find the original article but this might be a starting point.

Comment: You can find the proof [here](http://sites.mathdoc.fr/JMPA/PDF/JMPA_1852_1_17_A10_0.pdf). He consider numbers of the form $5N^2-1$ where $N$ is a product of primes, stating its prime factors are of the form $10n+1$ or $10n+9$ (not sure how he justifies this, I don't have time to translate the French right now).

Comment: Thanks.Where from did you download the paper? @wojowu.

Comment: Nowhere from. I dug out the title and then googled it.

Comment: The obvious justification is quadratic reciprocity, we have $\bigl(\frac{5}{p}\bigr) = 1$ for all odd primes $p \mid 5N^2 - 1$. Thus $p \equiv \pm 1\pmod{5}$, equivalently $p \equiv \pm 1 \pmod{10}$ for odd $p$. Consider only even $N$, then all prime factors of $5N^2 - 1$ are odd.

Comment: Can you please explain why the Legendre symbol is $1$ here?

Comment: $$p \mid 5N^2 - 1 \iff 5N^2 \equiv 1 \pmod{p} \iff (5N)^2 \equiv 5 \pmod{p}$$

Comment: Oops..it was easy. ..thanks.but why $ p \equiv \pm 1 \pmod{5}?$

Comment: I am getting $p \equiv \pm1 \pmod{10} $ first rather than $p \equiv \pm1 \pmod{5} $ using Gauss' lemma, although they are equivalent. Can you please tell how you got $p \equiv \pm1 \pmod{5 } $ before $p \equiv \pm1 \pmod{10} $ ?

Answer (score 2):

Assume that there are only finitely many primes $p \equiv 9 \bmod 10$. 
Consider the number $n = 5N^2-1$, where $N = 2 \cdot 3 \cdots p$ is a 
product of primes containing these finitely many $p \equiv 9 \bmod 10$.
If $q$ is a prime $q \mid n$, then $5N^2 \equiv 1 \bmod q$ and $q \equiv \pm 1 \bmod 5$ by quadratic reciprocity. Since $n \equiv -1 \bmod 5$, not all
prime factors $q$ of $n$ can be $\equiv 1 \bmod 5$. Thus there is at least one prime $q \equiv -1 \bmod 5$ dividing $n$, and this $q$ is not among the finitely many primes $p \equiv 9 \bmod 10$.

This proof works because there are only two residue clases modulo $5$ containing squares.

Comment: Please look at my last comment above. I got $q \equiv \pm1 \pmod{10} $ first but not $q \equiv \pm1 \pmod{5} $ . Am I doing mistake?

Comment: @mathisfun The two are equivalent since any prime above $2$ is odd.

Comment: Yeah..I know that. I applied Gauss' lemma and I got $ q \equiv \pm1 \pmod{10} $ first. So I just curious how you guys got $ q \equiv \pm1 \pmod{5} $.